# Listening for the response of dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

In my current project, some of the components are stateful. Some state properties depend on the result of the dispatch method.

```
this.props.dispatch({
  type: Constants.CONTRACT_DELETE_START,
  payload: {
    contract: contract
  }
});
```

Basically I need to get a response from this, like so:

```
this.props.dispatch({
  type: Constants.CONTRACT_DELETE_START,
  payload: {
    contract: contract
  }
})
.catch(err => {
   this.setState({
     foo: "bar"
   });
})
```

Is it possible to do it without having to carry `foo: bar` logic to the Redux store?

Ps. I'm using Redux Saga for my actions.

Comment: You're talking about sagas, but don't provide your redux saga code. Could you please show what you tried so far there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the promise thing (how to resolve or reject **in saga**) but you can also do like this:

```
this.props.dispatch({
  type: Constants.CONTRACT_DELETE_START,
  payload: {
    contract: contract,
    callback: () => {
      // Do your stuff here
    }
  }
})
```

Just pass a callback here and call this in your saga depending on your logic.

Comment: You usually want to keep your actions serializable, i.e. just containing plain objects and no callback functions so that things like time-travel debugging and so on continue to work.